# how can I replicate accelerate (apple DSP library) functions in windows?

Tags: c++, windows, vector, accelerate-framework

I'm going to make this as succinct as I can:

I have a project that I am needing to port to windows due to some very specific hardware constraints. There's a little utility class which performs vector distance calculations using Accelerate, the Apple DSP library. I need to rewrite this so that it functions without said library, but have been unable to find a suitable replacement. What is my best course of action?

```
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>

inline float distBetween(float *x, float *y, unsigned int count) {
    float *tmp = (float*)malloc(count * sizeof(float));
    //  float tmp[count];
    //t = y - x
    vDSP_vsub(x, 1, y, 1, tmp, 1, count);
    //t.squared
    vDSP_vsq(tmp, 1, tmp, 1, count);
    //t.sum
    float sum;
    vDSP_sve(tmp, 1, &sum, count);
    delete tmp;
    return sqrt(sum);
}

inline float cosineDistance(float *x, float *y, unsigned int count) {
    float dotProd, magX, magY;
    float *tmp = (float*)malloc(count * sizeof(float));

    vDSP_dotpr(x, 1, y, 1, &dotProd, count);

    vDSP_vsq(x, 1, tmp, 1, count);
    vDSP_sve(tmp, 1, &magX, count);
    magX = sqrt(magX);

    vDSP_vsq(y, 1, tmp, 1, count);
    vDSP_sve(tmp, 1, &magY, count);
    magY = sqrt(magY);

    delete tmp;

    return 1.0 - (dotProd / (magX * magY));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vector functions are usually implemented through a specific assembly language instructions. This implementation is very slow. Perhaps you need a library that uses the SSE instructions.

In your code, all the arguments stride_x, stride_y, stride_res equal to 1, so I recommend you remove them from the functions arguments. Сode should be faster.

```
//t = y - x    
float
vDSP_vsub(float *x, int stride_x, float *y, int stride_y, float *res, int stride_res, int count)
{
    while(count > 0) 
    {
        // may be *x - *y ?
        *res = *y - *x;
        res += stride_res;
        x += stride_x;
        y += stride_y;
        count--;
    }    
}

//t.squared
float
vDSP_vsq(float *x, int stride_x, float *res, int stride_res, int count)
{
    while(count > 0) 
    {
        *res += (*x) * (*x);
        x += stride_x;
        res += stride_res;
        count--;
    }    
}

//t.sum
float
vDSP_sve(float *x, int stride_x, float *res, int count)
{
    *res = 0.0;
    while(count > 0) 
    {
        *res += *x;
        x += stride_x;
        count--;
    }    
}

float
vDSP_dotpr(float *x, int stride_x, float *y, int stride_y, float *res, int count)
{
    *res = 0.0;
    while(count > 0) 
    {
        *res += (*x) * (*y);
        x += stride_x;
        y += stride_y;
        count--;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Intel's IPP libraries](http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/composerxe/en-us/2011Update/ippxe/ipp_manual_lnx/index.htm).